# MSCVP120D.dll missing even though redistributable is installed?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, linker, runtime-error

I'm creating a C++ application using Visual Studio 2013 and using libraries such as FMOD and SDL. I'm trying to package the application to run on other machines through the .exe. I have all my library paths correct and dependencies referenced locally, but when I run the .exe on another machine I get the "MSCVP120D.dll not found" error.

I have installed the Visual Studio 2013 redistributable on these test machines (Since it's 120.dll) and yet the error persists.

As far as I'm aware, other than the libraries specified, which all work, I'm only using standard libraries and windows.h.

I have been told another option is to install the dll file locally and link it statically to the CRT, but honestly I don't know enough to know if this is a correct option or not.

For more information, I'm on a Windows 8.1 machine and have tested on Windows 8 and 7, with no success other than on my own machine.

Comment: You are compiling and linking as a debug build. And the debug-library are not redistributable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are compiling your program in debug-mode and linking to the MS C++ debug-runtime.

Change to release-configuration, and either compile it statically or preferably add the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) to your deployment (the last part is not neccessary if it's already installed).

Comment: Worked, never had to change to a release build before, you learn something new everyday :D Thank you very much